# Why $n^{|s|}$ - the definition of Grossman-Larson product

Tags: combinatorics, trees

A forest of rooted non-planar trees $t_{i}$ is a set (unordered collection) of rooted non-planar trees, i.e. of directed graphs with a distinguished vertex (root) such that there exists a unique path from the root to any other vertex.

Given a forest $F=t_{1}\cdots t_{n}$, its **grafting** is a rooted non-planar tree $B^{+}(F)$ obtained from $F$ by connecting all roots of the forest to a new vertex, which is declared the root of the resulting tree. For instance, given trees `(A,B,(C,D)E)F` ([Newick format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format)) and `(G, H)I`, their grafting is `((A, B, (C, D)E)F, (G, H)I)J`. **Ungrafting** $B^{-}(t)$ is an operation on trees inverse to grafting, i.e. it turns a rooted tree into a forest by deleting the root.

Grossman-Larson product $*$ of forests $t_{1}\cdots t_{n}$ and $s_{1} \cdots s_{m}$ is defined [here](https://ntnuopen.ntnu.no/ntnu-xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/3032313/Adrian%20de%20Jesus%20Celestino%20Rodriguez_PhD.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) (page 33) in the following way:

> If $t_{1}\cdots t_{m}$ is an empty forest, denoted as $\mathbf{1}$, then $$1 * s_{1}\cdots s_{m}=s_{1}\cdots s_{m}$$. If $t_{1}\cdots t_{n}$ is not empty, then $t_{1}\cdots t_{n} * s_{1}\cdots s_{m}$ is the sum of **ungraftings** of trees, obtained by **grafting** $s$ the forest $s_{1}\cdots s_{m}$ and then attaching roots of elements of the forest $t_{1}\cdots t_{n}$ to $s$ in all $n^{|s|}$ possible ways, where $s:=B^{+}(s_{1}\cdots s_{m})$.

An example given in the text is

[image: Example of Grossman-Larson product]

The definition itself seems clear, but that "all $n^{|s|}$" part doesn't make sense to me. Suppose we have a tree $s=B^{+}(s_{1}\cdots s_{m})$ that contains $|s|$ vertices, and we have $n$ trees in the forest $t_{1}\cdots t_{n}$. Each of them we can attach to any of $|s|$ vertices independently, giving us $|s|^{n}$ choices. Is this a typo, or do I miss something?